# How to capture data from third party web site?

Tags: web-scraping, capture

For example, I would just like to capture the data for the 30 latest events for the scrolling info shown on this URL:

http://hazmat.globalincidentmap.com/home.php#

Any idea how to capture it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language are you using? In Java, you can get the page HTML content using something like this:

```
URL url;
InputStream is = null;
BufferedReader br;
String line;

try {
    url = new URL("http://hazmat.globalincidentmap.com/home.php");
    is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Here you need to parse the HTML lines until 
        //you find something you want, like for example
        // "eventdetail.php?ID", and then read the content of
        // the <td> tag or whatever you want to do.

    }
} catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
     mue.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
     ioe.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (is != null) is.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {

    }
}
```

Example in PHP:

```
$c = curl_init('http://hazmat.globalincidentmap.com/home.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$html = curl_exec($c);

if (curl_error($c))
    die(curl_error($c));

$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($c);
```

And then parse the contents of `$html` variable.

Comment: Well, I was hoping to use the info in a widget on a website... so html or php would work... how would I parse the contents of $html variable? Can you give an example and what output would be? Thanks.

Comment: So there you have both examples, now you only  need to work a bit with the parsing to get the real data you want to have.

Comment: How would I parse the contents of $html variable? Can you give an example and what output would be? Thanks.

Comment: Also, it seems that the website info is dynamic, how would I go about limiting the info to the most current 30 events? Sort of new to this whole thing. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you go to the website and have a look to the source code (control+U  or using developer tools in the browser) you can have an idea about how the output will be. You need to find a pattern that matches to the lines you want to see and store the information in a List, for example, to persist it later to a database or send it throught the network to some other service. Anyway, that is another different subject, if the above answer is OK for your question, an accepted asnwer would help :P, thanks.

Comment: I think that you already have only the last 30 events in that table.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess the biggest issue is how do I find the upper bound for "eventdetail.php?ID=" and then count the top 30? Along with a dynamic refresh? Maybe this is a different type of question? Thanks again.